# RegEx Google Analytics Goal with Parameters

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am currently setting up tracking and goals for a client.

I am setting a Destination goal where the Regular express is set to something along the lines of:

.*/summits-thank-you/ however we have changed the URL to /summits/?newsletter=true

The question is how do I get /summits/?newsletter=true to work in Regular Express like /summits-thank-you/?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Would `.*/summits/\?` do the trick? Or `.*/summits/\?newsletter=true`?